# AngularJS Controller is not binding with HTML

Tags: angularjs, controller, factory

Please find my my controller javascript file below -

```
angular.module('myApp', []);

angular.module('myApp').factory('myFactory', function () {
  var myFactory = {};

  myFactory.list = [];

  myFactory.add = function (message) {
    myFactory.list.push({ id: myFactory.list.length, text: message });
    //return myFactory;
  };

  return myFactory;
});

angular.module('myApp').controller('Controller1', function (myFactory) {

  var myVar = this;

  myVar.myList = myFactory.List;

});

angular.module('myApp').controller('Controller2', function (myFactory) {

  var myVar = this;

  myVar.newMessage = 'Hello World!';

  myVar.addMessage = function (message) {
    myFactory.add(message);
    myVar.newMessage = '';
  };

});
```

And also my HTML file below -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <title></title>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="myApp">

      <div>
        <h1>Services</h1>

        <div' ng-controller="Controller1">
          <p ng-repeat="m in myList">{{ m.id }}: {{ m.text }}</p>
        </div'>
      </div>


      <div ng-controller="Controller2 as post">
        <form ng-submit="post.addMessage(post.newMessage)">
          <input type="text" ng-model="post.newMessage">
          <button type="submit" 
            ng-click="post.addMessage(post.newMessage)">
            Add Message
          </button>

        </form>
      </div>

    </body>
  </html>
  <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
```

I can't see the data returning by the 'Controller1'

When I run the code I can't see the result which is coming from Controller1, which means the list is not binding with the ng-controller in .html page

Please tell me where I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are not referencing your list properly:

```
<p ng-repeat="m in myList">{{ m.id }}: {{ m.text }}</p>
```

If you are going to use `myVar` to store your list, you should use `Controller as` syntax so that your template has a reference to the variable:

```
<div ng-controller="Controller1 as myVar">
  <p ng-repeat="m in myVar.myList">{{ m.id }}: {{ m.text }}</p>
</div>
```